# Expectation of standard exponential squared given sum of two standard exponentials

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, exponential-distribution

So I have been working on this question for a while and made some progress , but I run into a problem about the normalizing constant. The question is, for $X$ and $Y$ i.i.d. standard exponential, find $\mathbb{E}(X^2 | X+Y = 4)$.

I started with computation of the conditional probability:
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
P(X^2 = k | X+Y=4) &= P(X = \sqrt{k}| X+Y=4) \\
&= P(X = \sqrt{k}, X+Y=4) / P(X+Y=4) \\
&= P(X = \sqrt{k}) P(Y = 4 - \sqrt{k}) / P(X+Y=4)
    \end{split}
\end{align}
for $k > 0$, where I used the positivity of exponential distribution and independence between $X$ and $Y$.

Then I use the fact that sum of $n$ i.i.d. $Exp(\lambda)$ is $Ga(n, \lambda)$, so $Z:= X+Y \sim Ga(2,1)$. So $f_Z(z) = z \exp(-z)$. Plug in, get 
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
P(X^2 = k | X+Y=4) &= P(X = \sqrt{k}) P(Y = 4 - \sqrt{k}) / P(X+Y=4) \\
&= \exp(-\sqrt{k}) \exp(-(4-\sqrt{k})) / [4 \exp(-4)] = 1/4
    \end{split}
\end{align}

But as $k \in (0, 16)$, $\int_0^{16} P(X^2 = k | X+Y=4) dk = 16/4 = 4$, which obviously is wrong, because the conditional probability should integrate to 1. Can anyone point out where I made a mistake? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you explain how $k$ disappeared from the expression "$\exp(-\sqrt{k})\ldots=1/4$"?

Comment: As a hint to an easier approach, show that $X$ has a uniform distribution conditional on $X+Y.$  This is intuitively evident, because $X$ and $Y$ can be interpreted as waiting times in a Poisson process and therefore--by the basic properties of such processes--the time to the first event, $X,$ is uniformly distributed between the start and the time to the second event (which is $X+Y$).  Thus you can hope that the calculation of the conditional distribution of $X$ is simple.

Comment: Also, you are working with continuous random variables. So you cannot work with a conditional probability like $P(X^2=k\mid X+Y=4)$ the way you have written because $P(X+Y=a)=0$ for any $a$ (And $P(X=a)=P(Y=b)=0$ for any $a,b$ ). You should have worked with the conditional distribution function or the conditional density instead; it's the *density* that should integrate to $1$.

Comment: @whuber $k$ is cancelled out because it's $\exp(- \sqrt{k} - 4 + \sqrt{k})$

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for pointing that out. Could you tell me what would be a right way to do it then? Use a change of variable to find out the conditional density of $X^2$ I guess?

Comment: That is a clear indication that your expression was incorrect to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use @whuber's suggestion of finding the distribution of $X$ conditioned on $X+Y$, you can take the familiar route of change of variables.

Joint density of $(X,Y)$ is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=e^{-(x+y)}\mathbf1_{x>0,y>0}$$

Change variables $(X,Y)\to (U,V)$ such that $U=X$ and $V=X+Y$.

So, $x=u\,,\,y=v-u$ and $x>0,y>0\implies 0<u<v<\infty$. Jacobian of transformation is unity. So joint density of $(U,V)$ is

\begin{align}
f_{U,V}(u,v)&=e^{-v}\mathbf1_{0<u<v<\infty}
\\&=\underbrace{\frac{1}{v}\mathbf1_{0<u<v}}_{f_{U\mid V}(u\mid v)}\,ve^{-v}\mathbf1_{v>0}
\end{align}

The distribution of $X$ conditioned on $X+Y=v$ is thus uniformly distributed over $(0,v)$.

Hence,

\begin{align}
E(X^2\mid X+Y)&=\operatorname{Var}(X\mid X+Y)+(E(X\mid X+Y))^2
\\&=\frac{(X+Y)^2}{12}+\frac{(X+Y)^2}{4}
\\&=\frac{(X+Y)^2}{3}
\end{align}